# reading space separated data and pushing it into proper contaner

Tags: c++, stringstream, istringstream, ostringstream

I am facing a problem how to read space separated data from input stream.

Lets say we need to input J 123 7 3 M. First is letter and last is letter. The rest is int.

```
vector<int> ints;
vector<char> chars;
stringstream ss;

...

cin >> c
chars.push_back(c);
ss << c;
cin >> i;
while(ss << i) {
    ints.push_back(i);
}

...
```

But this code does not resolve the problem. I tried lots of combinations and still nothing.

I was thinking that I could read everything as char and then convert it to int.

I know that there are similar questions to that but in my case I would like to solve that without string and not dynami arrays (may be dynamic array but without set length).

EDIT

I managed to read such stram by:

```
char first, last;
int i;

std::cin >> first;
std::cout << first;

while(std::cin >> i) {
    std::cout << i;
}

std::cin >> last;
std::cout << last;
```

But there is one problem:
writing "F 1 23 2 2 W" displays F12322@. Don't know why there is "@" at the end.
Any thoughts?

EDIT2:

```
std::cin.clear();
```

after while loop solves the problem.

Comment: Add what is the error or result from the above program or a runnable code.

Answer (score 1):

In order to organize and add your data you could create a small struct which with an `operator>>` for example ([ideone](http://ideone.com/pSKVGS)):

```
struct line{
    char f1,f5;  // give them meaningful names
    int f2,f3,f4;
    friend std::istream &operator>>(std::istream &is, line &l) {
        is >> l.f1;
        is >> l.f2;
        is >> l.f3;
        is >> l.f4;
        is >> l.f5;
        return is;
    }
};


int main() {
    string input = "J 123 7 3 M\nK 123 7 3 E\nH 16 89 3 M";
    stringstream ss(input);
    vector<line> v;
    line current;

    while(ss >> current){
        v.push_back(current);
    }
    for (auto &val: v){
        cout<< val.f1 << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Each time you read something you can do whatever you'd like with the `current` line. If each lien does not have a specific meaning you could just do a

```
while(ss>>f1>>f2>>f3>>f4>>f5){    
    // do stuff with fields
}
```

Where `ss` is a [`stringstream`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/sstream/stringstream/stringstream/) but it could all so be `cin`.

Comment: Thanks for You answer! The problem here is that we use sting. Another thing: don't we use specified number of elements here?

Comment: The string here is just for demonstration purposes, as I said you could change the `ss` to `cin`. We don't use a specified number of elements as long as your data is in the format you've provided you'll be able to read an arbitrary number of those lines whatever they are.

Answer (score 1):

If you know the number of elements and its type then you can use the following code for

```
#include<vector>
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int i;
    char c;
    vector<int> ints;
    vector<char> chars;

    cin>>c;
    chars.push_back(c);
    for(int j=0;j<3;j++){
        cin>>i;
        ints.push_back(i);

        }
    cin>>c;
    chars.push_back(c);
}
```

Comment: That is the problem - i don't know the number of elements. Thanks anyways!